# Fluid full screen view transitions on iOS

Tags: ios, animation, view

I have a simple app that has a set of coloured views, one red, one green and one blue.

I am trying to make it so that when a swipe gesture is made the current view will switch to the next one in the list in a fluid manner, it looks like moving a long piece of paper with different colours on it.

Is there a way to do this (CoreAnimation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first look into UIScrollView. It seems to me that what you are trying to accomplish is the same you have, say, in Mobile Safari on an iPhone, when you show all your current pages and can go from one to the next by scrolling. [This tutorial](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/) is particularly close to what you describe.

If you are looking into more advanced kind of transformations, than Core Animation would be the option.

Actually, nothing prevents using both approaches, UIScrollView to handle the swipe, Core Animation to add more animation to the pack...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIScrollView to accomplish this.  Add all of your colored views as subviews to the scroll view.  Make sure your contentSize is setup appropriately and optionally setup paging to make the scrolling always snap to a certain border.  See the scroll view programming guide for more info [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html)